# How to prove this equation with Schwarz lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

I confronted with a question as follow:

If $f\in Aut(D(0,1))$ and $f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,1)$, then we have equation

$ \frac{2|dz|}{1-|z|^2} =\frac{2|df(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} $

I attempted to prove this equation with Schwarz-Pick therom. That is, if $f:D\to D$ is holomorphic, then $\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$ holds. Now, how can I know $f\in Aut(D(0,1)) $ implies the equality hold? Does it mean that if $f$ is a automorphism, it can be nothing but rotation?

Comment: What is $d$ in the above equation?

Comment: It's a differential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ has the same properties as $f$ and ${(f^{-1})'(z)=\frac 1 {f'(f^{-1}(z))}}$. Apply the inequality you already have to $f^{-1}$ and change $z$ to $f(z)$ to get the reverse inequality.